# Ansible replace seems to throw a parsing error?

Tags: replace, ansible

I'm trying to use the Ansible replace module to change some text in a file on a Windows Server 2019 Standard target. I'm using Ansible 2.8.3 running on Python 2.7

```
- name: REPLACE | Replace baseline.local with FQDN in InternetSettings.xml
  replace:
    path: '/path/to/settings.xml'
    regexp: 'baseline\.local'
    replace: '{{ FQDN }}'
```

I don't think the issue is the path, although one of the directories on the path to the file has brackets '{}' in its name. Could that be it?

I've tried to do the same thing with `win_lineinfile`, and it didn't throw an error with the same path, but it'd be difficult in this case to replicate the functionality of replace, which is really what I need.

EDIT 2: It works when I copy the file over to my local machine and delegate to 127.0.0.1. I'm running ansible from a Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) installation. It also works when I copy the file to a remote linux system and run replace there, so it seems to be a Windows problem.?

EDIT: The stack trace of the  error I'm getting:

```
"Exception calling "Create" with "1" argument(s): "At line:4 char:21
+ def _ansiballz_main():
+                     ~
An expression was expected after '('.
At line:13 char:27
+     except (AttributeError, OSError):
+                           ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
At line:15 char:7
+     if scriptdir is not None:
+       ~
Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
At line:22 char:7
+     if sys.version_info < (3,):
+       ~
Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
At line:22 char:30
+     if sys.version_info < (3,):
+                              ~
Missing expression after ','.
At line:22 char:25
+     if sys.version_info < (3,):
+                         ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
At line:24 char:32
+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My teammates and I suspect that this issue is the result of attempting to use an ansible module not built for windows on a windows target - more particularly, a target that doesn't have python installed. We suspect that some part of the compiling of python on the ansible controller or subsequent execution of the python binary on the windows target is what's really causing the problem here. We've decided on the workaround of just using win_shell with powershell's 'replace' to do what we need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your regexp string to double quotes:

regexp: "baseline.local"

Comment: What version of Ansible are you using? I am not seeing the same issue.

Comment: I'm using ansible 2.8.3 on python 2.7. Perhaps more relevant is that I'm running against a Windows Server 2019 tarrget

Comment: Perhaps. Unfortunately I don't have any Windows servers on-hand to verify that for you. If you are able to test the same code on a linux server and if it works, might warrant a bug to Ansible community.

Comment: It might, although I have to do some reading as to whether any ansible modules that aren't explicitly written for windows are expected to function correctly on windows targets. I haven't yet found anywhere that says the ansible replace module _shouldn't_ work on windows targets . . . but since it's not one of the "windows" modules maybe that's supposed to be understood? I don't know. Anyways, thanks for the help

Comment: @PeterWeeks I am getting the same error. Thanks for the powershell replace idea!